# Consuming a RESTful web service using Apache Camel

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, apache-camel

I am trying to consume a restful Web service using camel.

For that I am configuring dynamic endpoint url as the RESTful url is created at the runtime. Everytime I am checking if the particular endpoint url is registered as a route in my camel context using following method of CamelContext class.

Endpoint hasEndpoint(String uri);

In this case, if the endpoint is not registered then I add a route to my camel context using a custom Route Builder.

I am using camel HTTP component for this. This is working fine for me as of now.

However, I believe performance wise this is not good as everytime I have to check if a route is registered with the camel context and if not then register the same before making the webservice call.

Can some body please tell me if there is a better way to consume RESTful Web services in camel?

I also want to know if the RESTful webservice I am consuming uses OAuth 2.0 protocol, do I need to change anything in my code as I am just consuming it?

Regards, Nilotpal

---

Thanks for your reply.

I am checking if the route is already exists to make sure I don't end up adding duplicate route(s) to the camel context.

Regarding long lived routes and route dynamics, can u please explain a bit regarding this? How do I implement route dynamics?

It would also be helpful if you could point me to some CXF-RS producer example.. I read the documentation of CXFRS but could not understand it clearly.

Thanks
Nilotpal

Answer (score 1):

Exactly why do you need to check if the route is registred or not before making the call? You should perhaps setup a more long lived route and route dynamic towards resfull resources.

As for Rest with camel, I think the HTTP component does a great job, but there are higher level components to use as well, more designed for REST. 
[CXFRS](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html) and [Restlet](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html), producer examples for restlet can be found in the Apache Camel source unit tests, such as this [RestletProducerGetTest.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/camel/trunk/components/camel-restlet/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/restlet/RestletProducerGetTest.java?view=log).

As for oAuth 2.0, Camel has some oAuth support built-in, especially for google. Look for the [gauth component](http://camel.apache.org/gauth.html). There is even a tutorial, however it might not be aligned with your case, it still might give some background so you could solve your issues: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-oauth.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
```

My Aim

I am trying to intercept the incoming request and based on the ip of the incoming request i want to invoke dynamic endpoint of get offers

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){
     public void configure(){

     from("jetty:localhost:9000/offers")
     .process(new Processor(){
         public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            //getting the request object
            HttpServletRequest req = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);
            //Extracting information from the request
            String requestIP=req.getRemoteAddr();

            /**
             * After getting the ip address i do necessay processing
             * and then add a property to exchange object.
             * Destination ip address is the address to which i want to   
             * send my request
             */

           exchange.setProperty("operatorAddress",destinationIpAddress);


       }
      })
     .to("direct:getOffers")
     .end();
}
});
```

Now i will invoke the getOffers endpoint

so first i will register it

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){
     public void configure(){
         from("direct:getOffers")
         .toD("jetty:${property.operatorAddress}/api/v2.0/offers? 
          bridgeEndpoint=true")
        .end();

    }
});
```

so we can access the operatorAddress property of exchange object as

```
${property.operatorAddress}
```

also when we have dynamic routes then we need to call

```
.toD()   and not .to()
```