# Camel Rest api consumer using SpringOAuthResttemplate

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have to invoke a couple of rest web service from my spring boot application. I am planning to use the Camel to configure the flow and other EIP use cases. Some of the endpoints are using oAuth2 authentication. I am planning to use the Spring oAuthResttempalte. All the examples on the internet are either using restlet, CXF or camel-http.

[Camel Rest Consmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055957/consuming-a-restful-web-service-using-apache-camel?rq=1)

I am not able to find a single example with just spring resttemplate. Did anyone implement Camel Rest consumer using Spring Resttemplate?

Some of the Examples on the internet use a jetty server to consume a rest endpoint. Why do you need a jetty server for simple rest consumer?

Comment: If you have a copy of the Camel in Action 2nd ed book, then read the REST chapter as it covers how to use Spring RestTemplate with Camel

Comment: @ClausIbsen I have the book. In think you meant the chapter7-Microservices The RestTemplate is used to build a microservice. The camelRestConfiguration is used to consume. It is not using spring to post request to micro service.

Comment: You can use spring rest controller as-is, and then inject a producer template etc and use that to call into camel routes if needed, then you dont need to use rest-dsl but can use spring rest stuff if you want

Answer (score 3):

> Did anyone implement Camel Rest consumer using Spring Resttemplate?

I'm not aware of that and it's unlikely to found something in that direction because Camel already have bult-in components to [consume rest endpoints](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html).

> Some of the Examples on the internet use a jetty server to consume a rest endpoint. Why do you need a jetty server for simple rest consumer?

I believe that jetty was used as a consumer not a producer endpoint. So you won't need the "server". Or maybe you saw an example using jetty acting as a server to serve an OAuth endpoint?

If you excuse my approach, I'd suggest to remain with Camel HTTP/Rest capabilities to consume REST APIs using OAuth. I've found [this example on Gist](https://gist.github.com/rafaeltuelho/4d2449ac9b709fd29d79fa89acd8b48b):

```
from("direct:authService").tracing()
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
        .simple("<auth service context>/oauth2/token")
    .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod")
        .simple("POST")
    .setHeader("Content-Type")
        .simple("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .setHeader("Accept")
        .simple("application/json")
    .setBody()
        .constant("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client id>&client_secret=<client sec>")
    .to("https4://<remote auth service url>")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .log("response from API: " + body())
    .choice()
        .when().simple("${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} == 200")
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, AccessResponseToken.class)
            .setHeader("jwt").simple("${body.access_token}")
            .to("direct:<some direct route>")
        .otherwise()
    .log("Not Authenticated!!!");
```

If you want to stick into [`OAuthRestTemplate`](https://gist.github.com/cjstehno/4fcc88f9266ed4ae268c) you may implement a [`Processor`](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) or a [bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html) to wrap those calls and return to your route the authorization token.

Comment: thanks. I need to use oAuthTemplate because my client secret is preconfigured/populated using Springoauth. I am using the bean to invoke the class now. Surprised to hear camel don't have support for spring resttemplate.